# A very clever virus?

Tags: windows-7, memory, virus, memory-leaks

This happened after I'd deleted all my system restore points to save disk space on my 60GB SSD, and run a MBAM scan the day before.
Yesterday I downloaded a video file that would not play, though it had all its metadata correct. I dismissed it and downloaded a different version. About 2 hours later windows shouted at me because DllHost.exe was using almost all of my RAM. I killed it and came to the conclusion that the dll used to generate thumbnails had been compromised by the supposedly corrupted file. I tried to delete the video and it instantly came back with the permissions set so that I couldn't delete it anymore. I attempted to log in as the administrator account (which is usually disabled, but without a password) to discover that a password had been set. I plugged the disk into my Raspberry Pi to bypass the windows permissions and successfully deleted the file. I then logged back in to my PC and soon windows explorer was using about 4GB of my RAM. I killed it and attempted to replace it with a backup, but lacked permissions to rename it, which I used to have. I restarted explorer and nothing out of the ordinary happened, and my PC behaved normally for the rest of the night.

I turned it on this morning after a bit of thinking, and now svchost.exe was using immense amounts of memory. None of the services running under it were abnormal, so I killed its tree and it came back as expected, but using a normal quantity of memory. After 5 minutes or so it suddenly spiked back up. I installed BitDefender and told it to scan explorer.exe. It stopped working and when I restarted it had no GUI. I told the application to exit and all signs of it disappeared but the process was still running, and RAM usage was starting to climb. I attempted to kill it but task manager said I had insufficient permissions to stop the process, and it now had SYSTEM listed as its user. It seems far too clever to be "regular" malware, and I see no effect of it apart from using huge amounts of memory. It does this when not connected to the internet, so I don't think it's sending my data around.

I have now disabled my data drive and turned off the computer. I need to know if this is something that can be fixed or if my best option is to wipe my SSD and reinstall windows.

I do have another windows machine that I can use if extremely necessary, but otherwise I need my PC back by saturday.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing more harm then good replacing these files instead of understanding the reason they were consuming memory before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can suggest would be to enable command-line view in your Task manager.

- Hold CTRL+SHIFT and tap ESC.
- Go to 'details'.
- Right-click on the top bar where the column names are listed. ('Name', 'PID', etc.)
- Select 'Select columns'.
- Check 'command line'.

From here, I would take a close look at the command lines your system programs are running on. A common trait of Bitcoin Miner viruses is to hide in a suspect directory (eg C:\hgfjkhjfk) and name themselves something like *svchost.exe* to elude capture.

If you enable command-line view, you'll immediately see if you're running a miner (not to mention other nasties) because you'll see all the parameters the command-line program has been passed. If you're seeing switches that would indicate your machine is being used to mine bitcoins, find the location of the file and weed it out.

Comment: It's a good idea, but all the processes are from the right place. Unfortunately I think it's a nastier malware that a bitcoin miner, due to how it kills and breaks anything that tries to find it.

Comment: I would recommend you look at the command-line just to be sure, but unfortunately I can offer you no other help on the matter. System components taking up too much memory can be caused by lots of things; it may be an issue of another piece of software offloading more than it ought to (eg, a network scan slowing SvcHost). Good luck.